# Extracting difference values between two files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Working in linux/shell env, how can I accomplish the following:

text file 1 contains:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

text file 2 contains:

```
6
7
1
2
3
4
```

I need to extract the entries in file 2 which are not in file 1. So '6' and '7' in this example and now where it found them.
For example, 6, 7 in file 1

I already work with this awk command

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next}!a[$0]' file1 file2
```

But this command can only show the difference, So, 6 and 7 but not where it fouind it.

How can I do this from the command line?

many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by **where it found it**? Do you want to print filename with missing entries?

Comment: Yes i want to print the filname that contain difference.

Comment: So even when file1 has some extra lines you want to print them as well?

Comment: See also: [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-file-from-another-larger-file-in-bash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { seen[$0]=FILENAME; next }
  {if ($1 in seen) delete seen[$1]; else print $1, FILENAME}
  END { for (i in seen) print i, seen[i] }' file{1,2}
6 file2
7 file2
5 file1
```

While traversing `file1` we are storing column1 of each row in an array `seen` with value as `FILENAME`.  Next while iterating `file2` we print each missing entry and delete if entry is found (common entries). Finally in `END` block we print all remaining entries from array `seen`.

Answer (score 0):

The `comm` program will tell you what lines files have in common (or are unique to one file). `comm` works best when the files are sorted lexically.

```
$ echo "only in file1"; comm -2 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
only in file1
5

$ echo "only in file2"; comm -1 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
only in file2
6
7

$ echo "common to file1 and file2"; comm -1 -2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
common to file1 and file2
1
2
3
4
```